# Why would `_getstream` fail?

Tags: c++, file, fopen

The exception mentions

```
FILE* __cdecl _getstream
```

I'm calling `fopen` and it keeps crashing.

```
AfxMessageBox("getting here 1");
FILE* filePtr = fopen(fileName, "rb");
AfxMessageBox("getting here 2");
```

For some reason, I never get to the second message box. Interestingly, when I'm in debug mode, the app works perfectly. Why?

Comment: I would almost suspect a permissions related problem.  Running in debug mode means elevated?  What OS and what development environment?

Comment: What is the "FILE * __cdecl _getstream" at the top of your message for? Also, you don't need parentheses around the "rb".

Answer (score 2):

I think memory corruption.  On Windows (which the __cdecl makes me think you are using), there is the gflags utility which comes with the Windows Debugging Tools.  With it, you can make each heap allocation have it's own page -- this will help catch memory overruns and double freeing immediately at the point of the problem.

I wrote up instructions on my blog:

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2007/02/06/6-_2200_Pointers_2200_-on-Debugging-Unmanaged-Code.aspx

There are other tips for finding this kind of bug there too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect there's nothing wrong with that part of your program. The most likely scenario is that you've got some kind of memory corruption earlier in the code, and that just happens to be where it shows up.

Have you tried running it through the rest of the program (after that part) in debug mode? If it *is* some kind of memory corruption, the debug-mode allocator should catch it when it goes to deallocate the corrupted areas of memory, if not sooner. Assuming you're using a compiler with a thorough debugging memory allocator, of course.

Comment: The problem is the issue doesn't happen in debug mode. 
And it also only happens for some files, not all. 
I think you're right. 
I guess I'm going to go look at the memory allocation for the whole process. Not easy in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will affect many people since this is fairly obscure, but if you get your FILE* like this:

```
HANDLE hMyFile = CreateFile(...);
FILE* pFile = _fdopen( _open_osfhandle((long)hMyFile, <flags>), "rb" );
CloseHandle(hMyFile);
```

Then you'll leak a stream for each file you open.  After doing _open_osfhandle and _fdopen, you must call fclose() on the pFile to close your handle.  CloseHandle is apparently not smart enough to free the cruft that fdopen associates with your handle, but fclose is smart enough to close your handle along with the FILE*-related cruft.

The app I was working on did this because a certain API passed around HANDLEs, and a particular implementor of the API needed a FILE*, so the implementor did the _fdopen/_open_osfhandle stuff to get a FILE*.  However, this meant that the caller's CloseHandle call was insufficient to fully close the HANDLE.  The fix was to duplicate the incoming HANDLE first, then the FILE* code could properly fclose() the FILE* without breaking the caller's HANDLE.

Sample broken program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  for(int x = 0;x < 1024; x++)
  {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"c:\\temp\\rawdata.txt",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    FILE* pFile =  _fdopen( _open_osfhandle((long)hFile, _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY), "rb" );
    assert(pFile); // this assert will go off at x=509, because _getstream() only has 512 streams, and 3 are reserved for stdin/stdout/stderr
    CloseHandle(hFile);
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess that something is wrong with fileName (does it have trailing zero ?)

Try to comment *fopen* line out and see what will happen.